# android studio device monitor no devices

Tags: android, sqlite, device, monitor

I am trying to view a database that I created in Android Studio, but when I go to the Android Device Monitor it says I have no devices. I don't know how to get my program in the device monitor.
My database code is as follows:

```
public class DatabasHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "animals.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "animals_table";
    public static final String ID = "Animal_ID";
    public static final String STAFF = "Staff_name";
    public static final String ACTIVITY = "Activity";
    public static final String DETAIL = "Detail";
    public DatabasHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ACTIVITY TEXT,DETAIL TEXT) ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    }
}
```

But I don't think it is my code as it works fine. If anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: Connect a real device or run it on virtual device.

Comment: Have you start emulator to have a device running ?